# Can I work on Selenium and Android in same workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium

For a project I am writing Selenium test cases for automation. On the other hand for other project I am designing a page in Android.

I have created some part of page in Android and now need to finish Selenium test cases. But as soon as I run one big error came. Then I thought that I have to change my workspace and kept Selenium test cases in another work space even then error is coming (different error).

Below is the error after changing workspace:

```
org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot find class in classpath: inventory
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)  at
org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)  at
org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)    at
org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
    at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown
Source)     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)   at
org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)     at
org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)     at
org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)    at
org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)   at
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)    at
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)    at
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create both projects in same work space.

Comment: But its not running... Rightclick on any class-->usually we will see run as "TestNG" or jnuit  but this newly created project is not showing any run configurations...I have added TestNG libraries everything but no joy :(